# Why i can't use fronts local at aframe?

Tags: aframe

If trying to implement a text element with German "Umlaute".
I want to use fronts to solve the Problem.

But if i trying to use fronts local from my computer it still doesn’t work.

So why i can use a front by using an link, and not with an local file?

For the first example ive copied the Syncopate-Regular.json and the Syncopate-Regular.png file at the direktory my index file are. This dosnt not working but the second works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve your files from a local web server.

Comment: Thank you.
this fixes the problem that nothing is displayed, but umlauts are not displayed with a created msdf-front anyway.